# parameterizing struts2 s:iterate tag

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, loops

I using struts2 "s:iterate" tag. My collection name keeps on changing. So i wants to use an expression for specifying the value. According tld expressions are not allowed for "value" in "s:iterate" tag.

is there way to keep the value variable, instead of a static value.

```
     <s:iterator value="${param.listName}" status="status" > 
    </s:iterator>
```

Something like above.I would like use the listName from request parameter to specify the name of the collection to the iterate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
<s:iterator var="reportHeader" value="%{#session.myList}" status="headerNumber" >
</s:iterator>
```

yep works like a charm.

Update:

`myList` in `session.myList` is a `String` which represents the key.

So corresponding action code will be

```
public String execute(){
  HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();
  session.setAttribute("myList", new ArrayList<String>());
  return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: in my case i cant hardocde the parameter name. Like the example you stated value="%{#session.myList}". I cant hardcode it to "myList" variable name. Even this name will be passed as a parameter. So value="%{#session.VARIABLE}". So i should be able to replace the value VARIABLE depending on the parameter.